# Difficulties adding to Arrays that are also part of a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class StudentDatabase {
private HashMap<String, int[]> quizmarks;

public static final int NUM_QUIZZES = 10;
public static final int MIN_GRADE = 0;
public static final int MAX_GRADE = 100;



public StudentDatabase(){
    quizmarks = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
}

public String formatName(String name){
    String caps = "";
    String lowercase = "";
    if(name != null && name.length() > 0){
        caps = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    }
    if(name.length() > 1){
        lowercase = name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return caps + lowercase;
}


public void addStudent(String studentName){
    if(studentName != null){

        int[] marks = new int[NUM_QUIZZES];


        quizmarks.put(formatName(studentName), marks);
    }
}

public int[] getQuizzes(String student){
    if(student != null){
        System.out.println(quizmarks.get(student));

    }
    return null;
}

public void changeQuizMark
        (String studentName, int whichQuiz, int newMark){

    if(studentName!= null){
        quizmarks.get(studentName);
    }
    if(whichQuiz <= NUM_QUIZZES){
        quizmarks.get(whichQuiz);
    }

    if(newMark > MIN_GRADE && newMark < MAX_GRADE){

    }
    quizmarks.put(studentName, new int[]{newMark});
}
```

}

For some reason Arrays were not fully taught to us and we have been encouraged to go online to get help with it so i'm trying to figure out first of all why its saying in the addStudents method that it "cannot convert an int to an int[]" when i'm pretty sure both sides are int[] arrays when i'm trying to assign "marks".

I'm also unsure, because I can't get past this error, how my changeQuiz, and newMarks fields are actually going to assign to the right part of the array. Each student should have an array of ten quizmarks basically. And i'm insanely stuck.

I apologize i'm trying to work on the formatting but its only my second time here and I completely forget how to format, its giving me major issues and i'm trying to follow the instructions as best as I can.

Comment: how to reproduce your error? You have another errors but I can't see the one you've mentioned

Comment: I know i'm using Eclipse not sure if its a glitch or what, but in the addStudents method its saying i'm trying to convert an int to an int[] on the line where it says:

"int[] marks = new int[NUM_QUIZZES]"

Comment: `int[] marks = new int[NUM_QUIZZES]` - it is completely legal statement

Comment: For some reason when I moved it outside of the scope of "if(studentName != null)" inside the addStudent method it corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main mistake is here:

`quizmarks.put(studentName, new int[]{newMark})`

You don't add new mark to already existed array of marks but create a new array with only new mark therefore deleting an old marks array. All you need is to get array you need and modify its element by index. Also made few minor improvements:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class StudentDatabase {
    private HashMap<String, int[]> quizmarks;

    public static final int NUM_QUIZZES = 10;
    public static final int MIN_GRADE = 0;
    public static final int MAX_GRADE = 100;


    public StudentDatabase() {
        quizmarks = new HashMap<>();
    }

    private String formatName(String name) {
        String caps = "";
        String lowercase = "";
        if (name != null && name.length() > 0) {
            caps = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        }
        if (name.length() > 1) {
            lowercase = name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        }
        return caps + lowercase;
    }


    public void addStudent(String studentName) {
        if (studentName != null) {
            int[] marks = new int[NUM_QUIZZES];
            quizmarks.put(formatName(studentName), marks);
        }
    }

    public void showQuizzes(String student) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(quizmarks.get(student)));
    }

    public void changeQuizMark(String studentName, int whichQuiz, int newMark) {
        if (whichQuiz < NUM_QUIZZES && newMark >= MIN_GRADE && newMark =< MAX_GRADE) {
            quizmarks.get(studentName)[whichQuiz] = newMark;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay great, i'm going to give this a shot here in a little bit just have to put my son to bed first then i'll be ready. Thank you for your help. I'll update you when i'm finished.

Comment: Okay it looks great, I have a couple questions about how it works.

In the changeQuizMark method. when you call "[whichQuiz]" it picks the array because its being called in the same line as quizmarks.get? and then newMark assigns the mark to the whichQuiz number of the array?

Comment: @vanhalendlrband, exactly